# Is "的" (de) used in Singlish for possession or subordination? Or neither?

Tags: english, chinese, creoles

In Singlish (Singaporean English creole), is 的 used? And if so, is it used for simple possession ("*Jenny de dog") or for introduction of a subordinate clause? ("*Jenny found last week de dog") Or both?

I would expect that the latter is more likely to be used because it's more different from how English would normally put it so there is more utility in deviating from standard English in this way. Possessive 的 is so similar to English's apostrophe-S that there would be little gained from the speaker's point of view by using the Chinese particle.

Comment: Near-duplicate of [Is "的" (de) used in Singlish?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/53097/is-%e7%9a%84-used-in-singlish)